How to save auto populated combo box value to SharePoint list in power Apps

In Power Apps, I am getting current user's manager name in Combo box control inside the edit form. But, I need to save the default combo box value in SharePoint list using button control. Give any suggestion...

To save the default combo box value .You should the set a default value in Default selected item property of combobox .You can set a value in square brackets [ "Default value"  ] in Default selected items in combobox property.While patching that particular value in column set as combox.Selected.value in particular column.
